# Запустить из браузера скрипт, а не показать его код

Tags: freebsd

Скачал форум на `perl - yabb2`, пытаюсь его прикрутить к `Freebsd`.
Стоит `FreeBSD`, `Apache`, и сайт, также с перловыми скриптами. 
Я просто положил папку с перловыми скриптами `yabba`  в подпапку этого сайта - и он теперь виден в браузере. Но при попытке запустить из браузера скрипт - по запуску: `192.168.1.10/cgi-bin/yabb2/Setup.pl` он не запускает скрипт `Setup.pl`, а просто выдаёт его код.
Как сделать чтобы он запускался ?
В скрипте первой строкой прописано: `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`
что работает с другими скриптами и права на файл тоже даны: `-rwxr-xr-x Setup.pl`

Comment: на самом деле проблема не во Free а в Apache - не знаю как указать в настрйоках httpd.conf исполняемость perl-овых скриптов нужной папки

Answer (score 1):

ну например можно написать такой конфиг для виртуального хоста

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "/путь_к_пректу/www"
     ServerName путь_к_пректу.my
     ErrorLog "путь_к_пректу/logs/apache.log"
     CustomLog "/путь_к_пректу/logs/apache.log" common

     Alias /cgi-bin/ "/путь_к_пректу/cgi-bin/"

     <Directory "/путь_к_пректу/cgi-bin/">
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

важно задать апачу SetHandler cgi-script и Options +ExecCGI на папку скриптов, и не забудь дать права на исполнение скриптам